# convert rows into columns according to data of cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input:

```
    Date       Region   Value
0   01-07-2020  IN     8.8794
1   01-07-2020  ROW    2.1990
2   01-07-2020  UK     8.1226
3   01-07-2020  US     6.9386
4   02-07-2020  IN     9.0087
```

output:

```
            Date        IN       ROW      US        UK

    0      01-07-2020   8.8794   2.1990  6.9386    8.1226 
    1      02-07-2020  9.0087    NaN    NaN       Nan
```

output be look like above.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `df.pivot('Date', 'Region', 'Value')`

Comment: @ Shubham Sharma, Thank you very much.